# What happens when converting double (or floats) to ints?

Tags: java, casting, 2d

I'm practicing some simple 2D game programming, and came up with a theory that during animation (the actual change in a image position is best calculated with floating point numbers). I have a feeling that if you move an image around with ints the animation won't be as smooth.

In Java it seems you can't draw an image with floating point numbers to give an image a position. But apparently when you initially declare your **x** and **y** 's, you can declare them as Double, or Float, and when it comes to actually drawing the image you have to cast them to ints. Like I find [HERE](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/showsrc/showsrc.php?src=../spaceinvaders/org/newdawn/spaceinvaders/Entity.java) :

```
    /**
 * Draw this entity to the graphics context provided
 * 
 * @param g The graphics context on which to draw
 */
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    sprite.draw(g,(int) x,(int) y);
}
```

My question is about how Java handles the conversion? 
If the code casts these doubles at the last minute, why have them as doubles in the first place? 
Does Java hide the numbers after the decimal?

I know in C and C++ the numbers after the decimal get cut off and you only see whats before it. How does Java handle this casting?

Comment: It just drops the decimal, same as C, C++.  http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/Casting/

Comment: You should do calculations in double as much as you can, and when you finally pass it to a method that accepts int, you do Math.round().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pixels on a display are discrete and limited in number; therefore display coordinates need to be integer numbers - floating point numbers make no sense, as you do not physically have a pixel at e.g. `(341.4, 234,7)`.

That said, integers should only be used at the final drawing stage. When you calculate object movement, speeds etc, you need to use floating point numbers. Integers will cause an amazing number of precision problems. Consider the following snippet:

```
a = 1;
x = (a / 2) * 2;
```

If `a` and `x` are floating point numbers, `x` will finally have the expected number of `1`. If they are integers, you will get `0`.

Baseline: use floating point types for physics computations and convert to `int` at drawing time. That will allow you to perform the physics calculations with as much precision as required.

EDIT:

As far as the conversion from FP numbers to integers is concerned, while FP numbers have a greater range, the values produced by your physics calculation after normalization to your drawing area size should not normally overflow an `int` type.

That said, Java truncates the floating point numbers when converting to an integer type, which can create artifacts (e.g. an animation with no pixels at the rightmost pixel column, due to e.g. `639.9` being converted to `639` rather than `640`). You might want to have a look at [`Math.round()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) or some of the other rounding methods provided by Java for more reasonable results.

Answer (score 4):

Java truncates the decimals. Eg:

```
(int) 2.34 == 2
(int) 2.90 == 2
```

The reason for not being able to draw at a floating position is simply that there's no half pixels etc :)

Answer (score 2):

Java casts floats to int by dropping the decimal. But I don't think having x and y coordinates in floats make any sense. You have pixel on the screen which cannot be presented in anything less than one pixel. For example you can't draw a pixel `.5px x .5px` because on the screen it will just be `1px x 1px` pixel. I am not a computer game programmer but I have written one animation engine in Java and it was very smooth. I can share this if you'd like.

Note that you should draw using ints but do all your calculation using doubles. For things like rotating or anything that relies on a mathematical formula should be done in decimal.

Comment: Floats are useful for various reasons -- among them, that `sin`/`cos` (almost a necessity for decent rotation) practically require them, and many matrix ops can benefit from the ability for numbers to take on fractional values.  You turn them into ints, you end up losing a lot of flexibility (unless you want to write your own integer trig functions and such).  So many will keep them as doubles or floats til they absolutely have to be ints.

Comment: This is true. I didn't mean to do your calculation in ints. In my application I still do all calculation in double and draw using ints. I will update to reflect this note.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar can I take a look at that?

Comment: You sure can. https://github.com/amir20/iAuthor/tree/master/animation/src/main/java/edu/gwu/raminfar/animation I have implemented my own easing with a simple animation queue that takes care of the threading. It works pretty well and its not a very big in terms of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason x and y need to be doubles is for when they need to be computed mathematically, for example:

```
x += (delta * dx) / 1000;
```

You want to avoid overflows and loss of precision up until you paint the pixel.

Comment: so i guess before the double is casted it's calculated to get as close to the nearest accurate int as possible? 
(if that made sense O_o)